# Skolem’s “Theorem 9” and the associated equation

Tags: number-theory, reference-request, diophantine-equations, quintics

In *Diophantine Equations* (page 209), Mordell writes:

> [Skolem] proved that the equation
> $$x^5+2y^5+4z^5-10xy^3z+10x^2yz^2=1$$
> has at most six solutions in integers $x,y,z$,
> and of these three are known, namely
> $(x,y,z)=(1,0,0),(-1,1,0),(1,1,-2).$

Question #1: Does anyone know if progress has been made on solving this equation since Mordell wrote that (1969)? I’ve been looking, but haven’t found anything.

Question #2: Is there a translation of Skolem’s book/paper anywhere, in which this “Theorem 9” can be found?

Comment: I searched with "skolem  the use of p-adic method"  and got many items in English. Note Skolem's English paper (1955) about a dozen pages

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Theorem (Bremner 1977):** T. Skolem's Diophantine equation
$$x^5 + 2y^5 + 4z^5 − 10xy^3z + 10x^2yz^2 = 1$$ has precisely three integer solutions.

Reference: [this paper](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0022314X77900099) in Journal of Number Theory, Volume 9, Issue 4, November 1977, Pages 499-501.